# Cannot clone Git repo into my live server with SSH

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to clone in a repo of a WP site that I have built.

I'm using BitBucket and I was able to set up my public and private key pair with that no problem. I then log into my live servers account via SSH in my GitBash terminal (I'm on Windows). When I try to clone my repo into the website's live folder this is what I get.

```
[Server-Name]$ cd domains-folder.com/
[Server-Name]$ git clone --recursive git@bitbucket.org:User/foldername.git
Cloning into 'domain-folder'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
[Server-Name]$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
[Server-Name]$ exit
logout
Connection to Server-Name.Server.com closed.
User@Computer ~/.ssh
$
```

Am I missing a step? I'm confused because when I logged into my server I SSH'd into it so shouldn't I have access? Please let me know what I can do, and if you need additional information I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that error message can have multiple reasons, usually because git can't connect to the user.

Check these:
Are you using the user which has the ssh key set up?
Are you connecting to the correct url?
Check if your key is loaded:

```
ssh-add -l
```

Here's a great troubleshoot page that should help you:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Troubleshoot+SSH+Issues#TroubleshootSSHIssues-Permissiondenied(publickey)orNosuitableresponsefromremote

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you are doing but if you are expecting the ssh keys you've loaded for your access from Windows to the "live server" to be available also on the "live server" to authenticate with bitbucket then you need to enable key forwarding in your "gitbash" client

For the ssh program this is the -A option to turn on "forwarding of the authentication agent connection"